# SQL: how to divide results into time-buckets and fill in missing data across groups of columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I have a very big PostgreSQL Timescale DB which looks approx. like so:

| src | dest | traffic | timestamp (type: timestamp) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 200 | 2022-12-11 00:23:51.000 |
| a | b | 200 | 2022-12-11 00:32:01.000 |
| b | a | 200 | 2022-12-11 00:49:01.000 |
| a | c | 200 | 2022-12-11 11:39:01.000 |
| a | b | 200 | 2022-12-11 11:57:01.000 |
| a | b | 20 | 2022-12-11 21:32:01.000 |

Users will be looking to sum the `traffic` between pairs of `src-dest`. For example, a user may ask to sum the `traffic` between `a` and `b`. Or,  several pairs, like (`a` -> `b` and also `a` -> `c` ) - which will make the result set bigger. That's OK: the number of pairs to be aggregated is finite, small, and limited. The user will not ask for more than 10 pairs.

Each src-dest pair should be considered "unique", meaning `a-b` is not the same as `b-a`.

The data should be bucketed into equal-width time-buckets across two timestamps. For example, 24 `50 minute` buckets from '2022-12-11 00:25:00.000' to '2022-12-11 19:35:00.000'.

The number of buckets is determined by me. I take the starting timestamp, ending timestamp, and divide them by X equal-width buckets (you can assume it's always 24 in this question).

Here's where I'm having issues - a few musts for the result:

1. ALL time-buckets in the range must be present in the result, per pair. So for the example above, the result should ALWAYS have 24 rows for the `a` -> `b` pair, each row representing 1 bucket. (This is where `time_bucket` function of Timescale fails)
2. The earliest time-bucket row should ALWAYS be the starting timestamp, in our example: `2022-12-11 00:25:00.000` (this is where `time_bucket_gapfill` function fails).

A must for the query:

3. The query should support multiple pairs. For example:

```
WHERE ((src = 'a' and dest = 'b') or (src = 'a' and dest = 'c'))
```

Example output (not related for example input).

For the `a` and `b` pair, 24 time-buckets starting at `00:25:00`, where traffic stopped sometime between `11:15` and `11:55`:

| time_bucket | src | dest | traffic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-11 00:25:00.000 +0200 | a | b | 48614 |
| 2022-12-11 01:15:00.000 +0200 | a | b | 49228 |
| 2022-12-11 02:05:00.000 +0200 | a | b | 49228 |
| 2022-12-11 02:55:00.000 +0200 | a | b | 48614 |
| 2022-12-11 03:45:00.000 +0200 | a | b | 49228 |
| 2022-12-11 04:35:00.000 +0200 | a | b | 49119 |
| 2022-12-11 05:25:00.000 +0200 | a | b | 27288 |
| 2022-12-11 06:15:00.000 +0200 | a | b | 26054 |
| 2022-12-11 07:05:00.000 +0200 | a | b | 25735 |
| 2022-12-11 07:55:00.000 +0200 | a | b | 25360 |
| 2022-12-11 08:45:00.000 +0200 | a | b | 26748 |
| 2022-12-11 09:35:00.000 +0200 | a | b | 24787 |
| 2022-12-11 10:25:00.000 +0200 | a | b | 23065 |
| 2022-12-11 11:15:00.000 +0200 | a | b | 20629 |
| 2022-12-11 11:55:00.000 +0200 | a | b | NULL |
| 2022-12-11 12:45:00.000 +0200 | a | b | NULL |
| .... | a | b | NULL |
| 2022-12-12 19:35:00.000 | a | b | NULL |

Comment: how do you determine how many buckets and what the end time is?  I don't see 2022-12-12 19:35:00 in your input data.

Comment: and how do you choose the start time?  I see a-b has a timestamp of 2022-12-11 00:23:51.000, which is before 2022-12-11 00:25:00.000

Comment: @dougp I calculate them before building the query. In general I always want X (integer) buckets starting at Z (timestamp) and ending at Y (timestamp), equal length. I then calculate the interval. For this question we can assume I always want 24 buckets of 50 minutes starting at 2022-12-11 00:25:00. And regarding the 2nd question: yes. The source data can have any timestamp. We should still limit the starting bucket with the desired analysis start time. The input and output examples aren't necessarily connected.

Comment: @dougp I've edited my question a bit to clarify further. Thank you.

Comment: 2022-12-11 00:25:00.000 to 2022-12-11 19:35:00.000 is 23 - 50-minute intervals.  Did you mean 2022-12-11 19:35:00.000 to be the start of the last (24th) bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following:

- A time bucket is 50 minutes
- The first time bucket starts at 00:25:00 in a day; the 24th, 20:25:00
- A list of (src, dest) parameters

An approach using standard PostgreSQL without timescaledb extension

- `cte_ts_params` for (`start_ts`, `end_ts`) parameters
- `cte_src_desc_params` for (`src`, `dest`) parameters
- `cte_time_buckets` for 24 50-minutes time buckets based on `cte_ts_params`
- `cte_src_dest_time_buckets` for all combinations (`src`,`dest`) x `time bucket`
- join them together to get results

```sql
with recursive cte_ts_params as (
select to_timestamp('2022-12-12 00:25:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as start_ts,
       to_timestamp('2022-12-12 20:25:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as end_ts),
cte_src_dest_params as (
select 'a' as src, 'b' as dest union all
select 'a', 'c'),
cte_time_buckets(bucket_ts, n) as (
select start_ts as bucket_ts, 1 as n
  from cte_ts_params
union all
select bucket_ts + interval '50 minutes', n+1
  from cte_time_buckets
 where n < 24),
cte_src_dest_time_buckets as (
select bucket_ts,
       src,
       dest
  from cte_time_buckets, cte_src_dest_params),
cte_src_dest_traffic as (
select date_bin('50 minutes', t.ts, (select start_ts from cte_ts_params)) as bucket_ts,
       t.src,
       t.dest,
       sum(t.traffic) as traffic
  from ts t
  join cte_src_dest_params s
    on t.src = s.src
   and t.dest = s.dest
 where t.ts >= (select start_ts from cte_ts_params) -- start of 1st time bucket
   and t.ts <  (select end_ts   from cte_ts_params) -- end of 24th time bucket
 group by bucket_ts, t.src, t.dest)
select t.bucket_ts,
       t.src,
       t.dest,
       coalesce(s.traffic,0) as traffic
  from cte_src_dest_time_buckets t
  left
  join cte_src_dest_traffic s
    on t.bucket_ts = s.bucket_ts
   and t.src = s.src
   and t.dest = s.dest
 order by t.src, t.dest, t.bucket_ts;
```

An example of output:

```
bucket_ts                    |src|dest|traffic|
-----------------------------+---+----+-------+
2022-12-12 00:25:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   1545|
2022-12-12 01:15:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   1102|
2022-12-12 02:05:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   3637|
2022-12-12 02:55:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   2060|
2022-12-12 03:45:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   1610|
2022-12-12 04:35:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   1150|
2022-12-12 05:25:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   2312|
2022-12-12 06:15:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   1382|
2022-12-12 07:05:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   1165|
2022-12-12 07:55:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |     63|
2022-12-12 08:45:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   2796|
2022-12-12 09:35:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   2452|
2022-12-12 10:25:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   1180|
2022-12-12 11:15:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   1646|
2022-12-12 12:05:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |      0| *
2022-12-12 12:55:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   2490|
2022-12-12 13:45:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   1688|
2022-12-12 14:35:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   1671|
2022-12-12 15:25:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   3363|
2022-12-12 16:15:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |    772|
2022-12-12 17:05:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   1019|
2022-12-12 17:55:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   2183|
2022-12-12 18:45:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |    945|
2022-12-12 19:35:00.000 +0200|a  |b   |   2468|
2022-12-12 00:25:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |      0| *
2022-12-12 01:15:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |   4333|
2022-12-12 02:05:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |   4266|
2022-12-12 02:55:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |    375|
2022-12-12 03:45:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |    154|
2022-12-12 04:35:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |   1991|
2022-12-12 05:25:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |      0| *
2022-12-12 06:15:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |   1646|
2022-12-12 07:05:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |   6056|
2022-12-12 07:55:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |   2531|
2022-12-12 08:45:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |   2987|
2022-12-12 09:35:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |   2965|
2022-12-12 10:25:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |   4107|
2022-12-12 11:15:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |   1276|
2022-12-12 12:05:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |    362|
2022-12-12 12:55:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |    534|
2022-12-12 13:45:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |   1194|
2022-12-12 14:35:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |    579|
2022-12-12 15:25:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |    362|
2022-12-12 16:15:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |    833|
2022-12-12 17:05:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |    348|
2022-12-12 17:55:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |   2401|
2022-12-12 18:45:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |   1708|
2022-12-12 19:35:00.000 +0200|a  |c   |   3101|
```

**UPDATE** per @zerohedge's follow-up question in comment

According to https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hyperfunctions/time_bucket/
that

> "bucket origin defaults to midnight on January 3, 2000, for buckets
> that don't include a month or year interval, and to midnight on
> January 1, 2000, for month, year, and century buckets."

I tested timescales-latest-pg14 docker image, which has

- PostgreSQL 14.5
- timescaledb extension 2.8.1

with the following query calling `time_bucket()` and `time_bucket_gapfill()` with required and optional parameters:

```sql
select time_bucket('50 minutes', '2022-12-12 00:32:00'::timestamp) as bucket_ts_with_default_origin,
       time_bucket('50 minutes', '2022-12-12 00:32:00'::timestamp, '2022-12-12 00:25:00'::timestamp) as bucket_ts_with_custom_origin,
       time_bucket_gapfill('50 minutes', '2022-12-12 00:32:00'::timestamp) as bucket_gapfill_ts_with_default,
       time_bucket_gapfill('50 minutes', '2022-12-12 00:32:00'::timestamp, '2022-12-12 00:25:00'::timestamp, '2022-12-12 20:25:00'::timestamp) as bucket_gapfill_ts_with_custom_start_finish;
```

Outcome:

```
bucket_ts_with_default_origin|bucket_ts_with_custom_origin|bucket_gapfill_ts_with_default|bucket_gapfill_ts_with_custom_start_finish|
-----------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
      2022-12-11 23:50:00.000|     2022-12-12 00:25:00.000|       2022-12-11 23:50:00.000|                   2022-12-11 23:50:00.000|
```

You can see that

- `time_bucket()` works if given a custom origin
- `time_bucket_gapfill()` doesn't work even given custom start and finish

Is it a bug, a feature, or something missed?

Comment: Thanks, you write "An approach using standard PostgreSQL without timescaledb extension" - is there a better approach while using Timescaledb's features? (except for `time_bucket` and `time_bucket_gapfill`, which are no good here)

Comment: @zerohedge please see *update* in the answer.

Comment: it's a feature, for now. The custom `start` in `time_bucket_gapfill` do not actually change the times the buckets start at, only the time that is gapfilled. Which sucks.

Comment: Your original answer (not using time_bucket) is portable.  It can be adapted to MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc. with minor tweaks.